# Is it possible to create Postgresql data source in Oracle Visual Analyzer?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm using OBIEE 12.2.1.2.0 and I want to create a connection to Postgresql there's no database type for Postgresql in 'Add a New Connection' form.

[image: Add a New Connection]

I would appreciate if any body help me to know whether VA supports Postgresql connections.

Comment: Which "12c" is that?

Comment: @Chris Actually, it's OBIEE 12.2.1.2.0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's 12.2.1.2 all there's to be said is: The version doesn't have it yet. DV has it already though so the upcoming 12.2.1.4 on-premises should be up-to-date again as well.

Comment: Thanks. When will 12.2.1.4 be released?

Comment: "soon" is all you will get from anyone. There are never exact dates until just before the release.

Can you close this thread please?